# Random scale of square makes a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

Why does this code generates a rectangle, not a square?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[scale=rnd] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every coordinate of (1,1) is multiplied with the value of `scale`. So you have two values `x` and `y` which will be multiplied with `rnd`. And of course `rnd` isn't equal for `x` and `y`.

To use `rnd` as an option of `scale` you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathparse{rnd}
    \draw[scale=\pgfmathresult] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[scale=1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to scale the square properly without using a variable?

Comment: @Jill-JênnVie: You can use `scale=2`. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, the same random scale affecting both x and y.

Comment: @Jill-JênnVie: You can use the option `cm`

Comment: And how to factor the random number in `\draw[cm={rnd,0,0,rnd,(0,0)}] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);`?

Comment: @Jill-JênnVie: You need a random numer. See my updated answer

Comment: @Jill-JênnVie: Does it work?